# How do I find out of what size a Float in Ruby is?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, double

According to [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Float.html) a Ruby Float is an "inexact real number using the native architecture's double-precision floating point representation."

Does that mean that on 32 bit Ruby they are equivalent to a C `float` and on 64 bit Ruby to a C `double`?

If yes, how do I find out which Ruby the program is running on (how many bits, to be precise) at runtime? It should work on any OS and any Ruby implementation (mri ruby, rubinius and jruby).

The solution I came up with:

```
def architecture_bits
  1.size * 8
end
```

Does that work under all circumstances? Is there a better/more elegant approach?

Comment: Whether on 32 or 64 bit, double precision usually means a 64 bit double.

Comment: I need to know for sure, are you sure?

Comment: All floats in Ruby are double precision

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of single/double precision floats isn't related to whether you're running 64/32 bit implementations of ruby, so your implementation will return the wrong answer on any 32 bit implementation of ruby.

Float defines constants such as `Float::MANT_DIG` and `Float::MAX_EXP` from which you can derive the amount of storage used by a float. It will be pretty uncommon for it not to be an ieee 754 double precision though (53 bit mantissa (of which 52 are stored), 1 bit sign, 11 bits exponent)

Comment: So basically, computers with 32-bit storage locations use two memory locations to store a 64-bit double-precision number.