# Size of numeric data types in Ruby

Tags: ruby, types

I know that Ruby has Float for real, Fixnum and Bignum for int.
But what about sizes of this types?

a = 1.23 // size of one Float in bytes?

b = 1 // size of one Fixnum in bytes?

c = 2**65 // = size of one Bignum in bytes?

I am trying to find a standard or specification

Comment: Ruby has just Integers since [Ruby 2.4](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/)

Comment: Ruby’s floats are 64 bits (nowadays) no matter what number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that Ruby has Float for real, Fixnum and Bignum for int.

This is not true.

`Float` does not represent real numbers, it represents *floating point numbers*. In fact, in the general case, representing real numbers in a physical computer is impossible, as it requires unbounded memory.

`Fixnum` and `Bignum` are not part of Ruby. Ruby only has `Integer`. The Ruby Specification allows different implementations to have implementation-specific subclasses, but these are then specific to that particular implementation (e.g. YARV, Opal, TruffleRuby, Artichoke, JRuby, IronRuby, MRuby, etc.), they don't have anything to do with Ruby.

In fact, even knowing the implementation is not enough, you have to know the exact version. For example, YARV had `Fixnum` and `Bignum` as subclasses in the past, but now it doesn't anymore, it only has `Integer`. And even back when it had them, that was *still* not enough, because they actually had different sizes depending on the platform.

> But what about sizes of this types?
>
> a = 1.23 // size of one Float in bytes?
>
> b = 1 // size of one Fixnum in bytes?
>
> c = 2**65 // = size of one Bignum in bytes?
>
> I am trying to find a standard or specification

Here is what the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) has to say on the matter [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## 15.2.8 `Integer`
>
> ### 15.2.8.1 General description
>
> Instances of the class `Integer` represent integers. **The ranges of these integers are unbounded**. However the actual values computable depend on resource limitations, and **the behavior when the resource limits are exceeded is implementation-defined.**
>
> […]
>
> Subclasses of the class `Integer` **may** be defined as built-in classes. In this case:
>
> - The class `Integer` shall not have its direct instances. Instead of a direct instance of the class `Integer`, a direct instance of a subclass of the class `Integer` shall be created.
> - Instance methods of the class `Integer` need not be defined in the class `Integer`itself if the instance methods are defined in all subclasses of the class `Integer`.
> - For each subclass of the class `Integer`, the ranges of the values of its instances **may be bounded**.

The ISO Ruby Language Specification does not mandate any particular size or representation for `Integer`s, nor does it specify any methods for querying this information.

> ## 15.2.9 `Float`
>
> ### 15.2.9.1 General description
>
> Instances of the class `Float` represent floating-point numbers.
> **The precision of the value of an instance of the class `Float` is implementation-defined**; however, if the underlying system of a conforming processor supports IEC 60559, the representation of an instance of the class `Float` shall be the 64-bit double format as specified in IEC 60559, 3.2.2.

The ISO Ruby Language Specification does not mandate any particular size or representation for `Float`s, *unless* the underlying system supports ISO/IEC 60559, in which case the representation must be as an ISO/IEC 60559 *binary64* double float. The ISO Ruby Language Specification does not specify any methods for querying this information.

The ruby/spec does not say anything about the size or precision of `Float`. In fact, it is *very careful* to not say anything. For example, if you look at [the spec for `Float#prev_float`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/float/prev_float_spec.rb), you can see that they are very careful to specify the behavior of `Float#prev_float` without ever referring to the actual precision.

[The ruby/spec for `Integer#size`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/integer/size_spec.rb) *does* say something about the sizes of specific *machine integers* in bytes. However, unfortunately, ruby/spec is kind of a mixture between specifications for the behavior of the *Ruby Programming Language* and the behavior of the *YARV Ruby Implementation*. I have the feeling that this spec is more like the latter.

For example, the cutoff point between fixnums and bignums in YARV is 2<sup>31</sup> on 32 bit platforms and 2<sup>63</sup> on 64 bit platforms, but on JRuby, it is 2<sup>**64**</sup> on both 32 bit and 64 bit platforms (and I think TruffleRuby is the same). So, 3000000000 will be a bignum on 32 bit YARV, but a fixnum on 64 bit YARV and JRuby, and 10000000000000000000 will be a bignum on both 32 bit and 64 bit YARV, but will be a fixnum even on 32 bit JRuby. For Opal, I think the cutoff point is different again, I think it is 2<sup>53</sup>. Other implementations may not even distinguish between fixnums and bignums at all, or they may have three or more different kinds of integers.

Also, it is very important to remember that this spec *only* specifies the **return value of the method `Integer#size`**. Nowhere does it say that this is actually how an `Integer` must be *represented in memory*.

By the way, you may be confused why I am talking about fixnums and bignums in YARV, when I said above that `Fixnum` and `Bignum` have been removed from YARV. Well, the reason is that the separate *classes* have been removed, but the *optimization* is still there. Which is another thing: the ISO Ruby Language Specification says that you are allowed to have implementation-specific subclasses of `Integer`, but it doesn't say what those classes are for. Neither does the ISO Ruby Language Specification force implementors to have optimized implementations for their subclasses, nor does it force implementors to have subclasses for their implementation-specific optimizations.

Compare that to YARV's *flonums* which are an optimized representation of 62 bit `Float`s, but they don't have their own class.

So, in (not so) short: the ISO Ruby Language Specification does not say anything about the sizes of `Integer`s, but it *does* say that *if* the underlying system supports ISO/IEC 60559, then the representation must be an ISO/IEC 60559 *binary64* double float. It does, however, say nothing about the size or representation for cases where the underlying system does not support ISO/IEC 60559.

The ruby/spec is careful not to specify anything about the sizes of `Float`s, but it *does* specify the return value of the `Integer#size` method. It does, however, not specify that this return value must in any way correspond to how `Integer`s are actually represented.

Here's what [the RDoc for `Integer#size` in YARV](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-size) has to say [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## `size` → `int`
>
> Returns the number of bytes in **the machine representation** of `int` (**machine dependent**).

So, it only says that it returns the number of bytes the `Integer` *would* have in the machine representation, but not that this is necessarily the way that it is actually represented. And it clearly states that the value is machine dependent.

Answer (score 3):

**Fixnum** has the [size](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-size) method

```
2**65.size # => 256
1.size # => 8
```

**Float** - from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815203/how-do-i-find-out-of-what-size-a-float-in-ruby-is#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20docs%20a,Ruby%20to%20a%20C%20double%20%3F) and also what Stefan pointed out in the comments, they're 64 bits.

**String** has the [bytesize](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/bytesize) method

```
 "test".bytesize # 4
```